# Python numpy multiplication stringwise

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array :

```
a= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I need to do some sort of string multiplication on this array as follows :

```
2*string(a) = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6]
```

Is there any way to do this in numpy?

Thanks

Comment: Try using  `np.repeat(a, 2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [np.repeat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
import numpy as np

a= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
result = np.repeat(a, 2)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy repeat:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
print(np.repeat(a,2))
```

Which gives:

```
[1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6]
```